# To input a list of positive or negative integers to find out if a number is even or odd using switch function c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

The limit is to make 10 input numbers

```
const int LIMIT = 10;

int main ()
{
```

This is just declaring variables

```
float counter ; 
int number ; 

int zeros;
int odds;
int evens;

cout << "Please enter " << LIMIT << "integers, "
     << "positive, negative, or zeros." << endl;

cout << "The numbers you entered are:" << endl;
```

From here I am trying to print out all the numbers that the user has inputted and checking if it is odd or even

```
for (counter = 1; counter <= LIMIT; counter++)
{
    cin >> number;

switch(number % 2)
{
    case 0:
```

So here I am trying to count zeros as even numbers so at the end the output of even numbers will include zero if the list has a zero

```
            if (number == 0 ){
                zeros++;
                evens++;
            }

    case 1:
        case -1:
        odds++;
}
}

cout << endl;

cout << "There are " << evens << " evens,"
     <<"which includes " << zeros << " zeros."
     <<endl;
cout << "The number of odd numbers is: " << odds
     << endl;

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `evens++` should probably be outside the `if (number == 0)` statement. Currently you are only counting 0 as even...

Answer (score 0):

The values should be initialized:

```
int zeros = 0;
int odds = 0;
int evens = 0;
```

Furthermore, the value of `evens` must be incremented for even numbers. In your code it is only incremented in the case `number == 0`.

```
switch(number % 2)
{
    case 0:
        if (number == 0 ) { zeros++; }
        evens++; 
    break;

    case 1:
    case -1:
        odds++;
}
```

You also need to insert a `break` after `case 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of your major problems is that you don't break out of your switch case labels. For example:

```
int a = 7;
switch(a)
{
case 7: cout << "case 7\n";
case 1: // This will execute if case 7 doesn't have a break statement.
}
```

In your case:

```
for (counter = 1; counter <= LIMIT; counter++)
{
    cin >> number;

    switch(number % 2)
    {
    case 0: if (number == 0 )
          {
             zeros++;
             evens++;
          } // Falls straight through to the next cases. Counting evens as odds
    case 1:
    case -1: odds++;
    }
}
```

And you only detect evens if number == 0, not if number modulo 2 equals 0.

Here's a rewritten version:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int LIMIT = 10;
int counter; // This is better as an int instead of a float
int number; // Also none of these variables need to be initialised
            // As they are guaranteed to be zero-initialised as global static variables
int zeros;
int odds;
int evens;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Please enter " << LIMIT << "integers, "
        << "positive, negative, or zeros." << endl;

        for (counter = 1; counter <= LIMIT; counter++)
        {
            cout << "Enter number " << counter << " : ";
            cin >> number;

                switch (number % 2)
                {
                case 0:
                    if (number == 0) zeros++; // If input equals 0, increment zero counter
                    evens++; // Increment evens if in this case label
                    break; // Break, don't want to increment odds
                default: odds++; // Default case, if not 0, must be odd.
                }
        }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "There are " << evens << " evens,"
        << "which includes " << zeros << " zeros." << endl;
    cout << "The number of odd numbers is: " << odds << endl;

    cin.ignore(); // This just discards the final '\n' newline character
    cin.ignore(); // This blocks the program so the console doesn't close immediately

    return 0;
}
```